# проверить поле swift3 на числа с точкой или запятой

Tags: строки, swift3

как проверить в свифт, что в string пришло или число или число с плавающей точкой или запятой

```
extension String  {
var isNumber : Bool {
    get{
        return ?
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Используйте NumberFormatter для этого:

```
extension String {
    var isNumber: Bool {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.decimalSeparator = "."
        if let _ = formatter.number(from: self) {
            return true
        } else {
            formatter.decimalSeparator = ","
            if let _ = formatter.number(from: self) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```